# Helmert coding for mixed models in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, categorical-data, categorical-encoding, contrasts

I am using R to analyse data from an experiment with six conditions. Condition has two dimensions: for cognitive load, I have two levels (`load` and `no load`) and for language structure I have three levels (`structured`, `partially structured` and `unstructured`). These are then fully crossed giving the six conditions. They are all between-subjects.

I want to run a mixed effects model with the two condition dimensions and the interaction between them as predictors, and a numeric `accuracy` dependent variable.

My supervisor mentioned that I could use Helmert coding for the structure conditions but I can find very little information about how this works and any resources I have found don't explain how the contrasts are generated in enough detail for me to know what the R code is doing. From what I can understand it does seem like the right coding scheme, as what I basically want to know is whether there's a difference between structured languages and the rest, and whether there's a difference between partially structured and unstructured languages - I think this is what *"comparing the mean of each level to subsequent levels"* is doing? But I'm really stuck on how to create these contrasts and then how to use them in a mixed model. Any help would be much appreciated - even if it's just to point me to any more detailed resources on Helmert coding.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using Helmert contrasts with lme4. First we smulate some data:

```r
set.seed(1)
n_group <- 10
dt <- expand.grid(X = LETTERS[1:3], G = LETTERS[1:n_group], reps = 1:2)
X <- model.matrix(~ X, dt)

dt$Y <- 1
myFormula <- "Y ~ X + (1 | G)"

foo <- lFormula(eval(myFormula), dt)
Z <- t(as.matrix(foo$reTrms$Zt))

betas <- c(1, 0.5, 2) # Fixed effects parameters

u <- rnorm(n_group, 0, 2) # standard deviation of random intercepts

e <- rnorm(nrow(dt), 0, 1)   # residual error

dt$Y <- X %*% betas + Z %*% u + e
```

Now we set the contrast matrix and specify it when we call `lmer`

````r
ch <- contr.helmert(3)   # Because X has 3 levels

lmer(myFormula, dt, contrasts = list(X = ch))
```
````

Comment: Thank you. What I'm not sure about is how to interpret the coefficients I get back from a mixed model when I've used Helmert coding for the structure variable. Instead of the named levels I get back coefficients for `structure1` and `structure2`. What is in the intercept and what are these coefficients for?

Comment: You're welcome. The interpretation of Helmert contrasts in a mixed model is exactly the same as for a non-mixed model. The fact that it's a mixed model is not relevant.

Comment: Sorry to be unclear, my problem is less that it's a mixed model and more that I've never used Helmert contrasts before, so I wouldn't know how to interpret the coefficients in a non-mixed model either.

Comment: Your question says "*But I'm really stuck on how to create these contrasts and then how to use them in a mixed model. Any help would be much appreciated*" and I thought I had answered that? Interpretation wasn't mentioned in your question at all so I would suggest asking a new question about interpretation.